# Sympy: Return fractions and not floats in solve

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following example:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x',real=True)
eq = x**4 + 4/9*x**2 - 13/9
sol = solve(eq,x)
print(latex(eq))
print(latex(sol))
```

This results in

```
x^{4} + 0.444444444444444 x^{2} - 1.44444444444444
\left [ -1.0, \quad 1.0\right ]
```

How can I make this to print (automatically) fractions instead of floats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Rational`.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> eq = x**4 + Rational(4,9)*x**2 - Rational(13,9)
>>> sol = solve(eq, x)
>>> sol
[-1, 1]
>>> print (latex(eq))
x^{4} + \frac{4 x^{2}}{9} - \frac{13}{9}
>>> print(latex(sol))
\left [ -1, \quad 1\right ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a flag that sympy recognizes '4/9' as 'Rational(4,9)' automatically?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Might be good to ask another question. I'd be interested too.

Comment: Hard for me to imagine that would be possible since python will calculate the 4/9 before sympy has a chance to see it, no? Of course you could just wrote a short wrapper if you don't want to type out Rational.

Comment: @VictorChubukov: Like you, I find it hard to imagine, for various reasons. But I've been wrong in my life so many, many times ...

Comment: @Julia As a shortcut, you can use `S(4)/9` instead.  The S (short for sympify) turns 4 into a SymPy object representing "4", and then division happens according to SymPy rules, resulting in a rational number. Some people write S(1)*4/9, to the same effect.